# How can I reset @AppStorage data when an App Storage variable is 0?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

```
import SwiftUI

struct characterDetail: View {
    
    @AppStorage("USER_HEALTH") var userHealth = 100
    @AppStorage("GOLD") var gold = 100
    @AppStorage("USER_PRESTIGE") var userPrestige = 0
    @AppStorage("USER_GLORY") var userGlory = 0
    @AppStorage("USER_ARMOR") var userArmor = 0
    @AppStorage("USER_SPEED") var userSpeed = 0
    @AppStorage("USER_DAMAGE") var userDamage = 0
    

    
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            ZStack{
                Rectangle()
                    .fill(.gray.opacity(0.1))
                    .cornerRadius(20)
                HStack{
                    Image("character")
                        .resizable()
                        .frame(width: 100, height: 100)

                    VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                        Text("Character Stats")
                            .bold()
                        Text("Health: \(userHealth)")
                            
                        Text("Gold: \(gold)")
                           
                        Text("Prestige: \(userPrestige)")
                        
                        Text("Glory: \(userGlory)")
                            
                    }
                    .offset(x:0, y:-10)
                }
            
            }
        }
        .frame(width: 350, height: 200)
    }
}
```

Every time I finish the missions user health goes down. When its come to 0 I wanna reset those all variables. Or the app get back to first shape like first time you build.

A restart function for game I tried to do someone but I couldn't. I hope I will find what I am looking for.
Thank you for your help.

```
import SwiftUI

struct firstMissionButton: View {
    @AppStorage("USER_HEALTH") var userHealth = 100
    @State private var countDownTimer = 5
    @State private var timerRuning = false
    private let timer = Timer.publish(every: 1, on: .main, in: .common).autoconnect()
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            
            Button(action:{
                timerRuning = true
                userHealth -= 20
            } ){
                Text("GO! Mission Time: \(countDownTimer) sec.")
            }.onReceive(timer){_ in
                if countDownTimer > 0 && timerRuning {
                    countDownTimer -= 1
                }
                else {
                    timerRuning = false
                    countDownTimer = 5
            }
            }.disabled(timerRuning)
        }
    }
}

struct firstMissionButton_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        firstMissionButton()
    }
}
```

this is the place I change the userHealth.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would recommend using an enum for the keys of your `@AppStorage`. This would also provide some sort of safety regarding typos in the `String` declaration in `@Appstorage`.

```
enum UserKeys: String, CaseIterable{
    case health = "USER_HEALTH"
    case gold = "GOLD"
    case prestige = "USER_PRESTIGE"
    case glory = "USER_GLORY"
    case armor = "USER_ARMOR"
    case speed = "USER_SPEED"
    case damage = "USER_DAMAGE"
}
```

Then create an extension for `UserDefaults` that removes exactly these keys:

```
extension UserDefaults {
    func resetUser(){
        UserKeys.allCases.forEach{
            removeObject(forKey: $0.rawValue)
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
@AppStorage(UserKeys.health.rawValue) var userHealth = 100
@AppStorage(UserKeys.gold.rawValue) var gold = 100
@AppStorage(UserKeys.prestige.rawValue) var userPrestige = 0
@AppStorage(UserKeys.glory.rawValue) var userGlory = 0
@AppStorage(UserKeys.armor.rawValue) var userArmor = 0
@AppStorage(UserKeys.speed.rawValue) var userSpeed = 0
@AppStorage(UserKeys.damage.rawValue) var userDamage = 0
```

and the function to remove would be:

```
UserDefaults.standard.resetUser()
```

It would be best to check for `userHealth == 0` and call the `removeUser` function at the place where you decrement it. But that is not shown in your code example.

### Edit:

It should be something like this but without knowing the rest of your logic it is hard to say if the timer should execute after userHealth is below or at zero:

```
Button(action:{
    
    userHealth -= 20
    if userHealth <= 0{
        UserDefaults.standard.resetUser()
        return
    }

    timerRuning = true
}
```

### Remarks:

This is just a hunch and not related to the question, but I think it would be best to move the code for manipulating an checking the health property to the `else` clause of the timer fired function.

Comment: I edit the question and add the place where I am chance the userHealth.

Comment: @FranzLiszt please see my updated answer.

Comment: i don't understand which page I use that extension. I use that button and I get the error 'Cannot find 'UserDefault' in scope'. I use the extension in different page and I get the error 'Cannot find 'UserKeys' in scope'.

Comment: when I trying to use all of them in same page then I have different errors.

Comment: @FranzLiszt sorry there was a typo. It should read `UserDefaults` and not `UserDefault`. You can place the extension in its own file the same for the enum.

Answer (score 2):

I think it’s already posted here, but try the following function:

```
extension UserDefaults {
    func resetDefaults() {
        let dictionary = self.dictionaryRepresentation()
        dictionary.keys.forEach({self.removeObject(forKey: $0})
    }
}
```

Comment: can you be a little more specific like am I gonna use that fun with if statement ?(if userHealt <= 0 {resetDefault()}) And where I am gonna use in @main part ? Sorry about that just I am new and I am trying to learn I saw that before but I didn't understand.

Comment: You can use it in an if statement like: `UserDefaults.standard.resetDefaults()` . Where are you going to check if `userHealth` is 0?

Comment: Won’t this remove everything in UserDefaults?

Comment: I used same variable different places one of them change all are change. Will there be a difference where the I am checking ? Because I don't know very well how work @AppStorage.

Comment: As @Joakim Danielson said, the above function will remove everythinh from AppStorage, isn’t this intended?